# ORA-02287 when inserting sequence value into Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(
    ID,
    FILE,
    URL,
    CREATED_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
    LAST_MODIFIED_BY
) VALUES (
    (SELECT mytable_seq.nextval FROM DUAL), ?, ?, 
    (SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL), ?, (SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL), ?
)
```

I get this error when running this query:

ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

What's going on? My background isn't Oracle, but I've not seen this behavior with PostgreSQL that I can recall. Am I accessing the sequence improperly?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28037413/3989608 and https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/ for more insight on how to handle auto-increment using sequences pre-12c release and identity columns on 12c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am inclined to use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, FILE, URL, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
                     LAST_MODIFIED_BY)
    SELECT mytable_seq.nextval, ?, ?, sysdate, ?, sysdate, ?
    FROM dual;
```

To be honest, though, I would be inclined to set up a trigger to set `id`, `created_date`, `created_by`, `last_modified_date`, and `last_modified_by`.  That seem like the best way to insure that these columns have the information you really want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `SELECT` statements,

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(
    ID,
    FILE,
    URL,
    CREATED_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
    LAST_MODIFIED_BY
) VALUES (
    mytable_seq.nextval, ?, ?, 
    sysdate, ?, sysdate, ?
)
```

- You can access the sequence directly.
- Same thing for the current date (which is `SYSDATE` in Oracle, not `NOW()`).