# Get the unique id the record got when inserting to a database table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table with a unique `id` column. When I insert data into the table, I increment the last `id`.

```
insert into my_table vlaues((select max(id) from my_table), 'etc', 'etc');
```

There can be multiple processes who writes into this table simultaneously.

Auto commit is `on`.

This table does not have any other unique column except `id`.

When I insert a record to the table, is there a way to get the `id` value the record got, after I insert the record?

As I can see, if I use `select max(id) from my_table` after insert, I may not get the id used in the insert statement since someone else could have inserted another record before I issue `select`.

Comment: This is not a safe way to have autoincremented IDs - simultaneous access will cause duplicate IDs (possibly causing unique key violations).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoincrement in oracle to already created table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037303/autoincrement-in-oracle-to-already-created-table)

Comment: Also check out [IDENTITY column autoincrement functionality in Oracle 12c](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/) and [Auto-increment primary key in Pre 12c releases](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/)

Comment: This question is not just about auto incrementing. I need to fetch the auto incremented value after inserting a reord

Comment: Then look at [Returning the sequence number of Identity column after Insert](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/returning-the-sequence-number-of-identity-column-after-insert/)

Comment: If you are using PL/SQL to insert, then you could use **RETURNING CLAUSE** See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472118/returning-the-value-of-identity-column-after-insertion-in-oracle/28472515#28472515

Comment: Use:`insert into my_table values(my_table_seq.nextval, 'etc', 'etc') returning id into :id;`

Comment: @LalitKumarB is `RETURNING` clause available before Oracle 12?

Comment: @LahiruChandima I always use trigers to track old data , anyway the returning clause that Lalit mention worh looking , it depends on what you need .. also Gorden Linoff has a nice answer too

Comment: @LahiruChandima, Yes, the RETURNING clause has had been since older releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle 12 finally has built-in identity columns.  So, if you are using the most recent version of Oracle, you can just use that.  Read about it [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php).

In earlier versions, it is best to use a sequence.  This guarantees uniqueness, even in a multi-threaded environment.  I always implement triggers to update the id column.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle) is an answer to a similar question, that explains how to do this.

Comment: I read your solution using a sequence, but it is not clear how I can fetch the value used for the `id` column when a record is inserted. Any idea?

Comment: @LahiruChandima why dont you use a triger ?

Comment: @Moudiz I am not familiar with triggers. I will look into triggers if they can be used for this.

Comment: @LahiruChandima You could see my answer to know how to fetch the values using RETURNING clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable( ID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID())
```

Also it is preferred to use [Sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) to get the auto incremented id.

If you want to get the sequence id after the insert you can try like this:

```
declare
x  number;
id number;
begin
x := your_sequence.nextval;
insert into mytable (column1, column2, column3) 
values (x, value2, value3) returning x into id;

dbms_output.put_line(to_char(id));
end;
```

Comment: @Lahiru Chandima:- Whats the issue with `returning` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use sequences in this scenario (although you may end up with gaps in numbers). You can get their current/next values using `seq_abc1.currval/nextval` .

Comment: The gaps are must, and usually there is nothing wrong about them. Without having gaps, one transaction would have to wait till other commits (rolls back), so the whole system would not scale well.

Comment: True, I should have said 'will' rather than 'may'

Answer (score 0):

> When I insert a record to the table, is there a way to get the id value the record got, after I insert the record?

Simply use the **RETURNING** clause.

For example -

```
RETURNING identity_id INTO variable_id;
```

**Test case** -

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, text VARCHAR2(50)
  3    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_id NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    INSERT INTO t
  5      (text
  6      ) VALUES
  7      ('test'
  8      ) RETURNING ID INTO var_id;
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID returned is = '||var_id);
 10  END;
 11  /
ID returned is = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

SQL> select * from t;

        ID TEXT
---------- --------------------------------------------
         1 test

SQL>
```

You could use the same technique of **RETURNING** for **pre-12c** release too, where you do not have **IDENTITY** columns. *The returning clause will return the values that you are inserting into the table.*