# invalid identifier when trying to alter column value to default in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created this sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE stud_seq
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 99999
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

And I have this table called *student*

```
Name                 Null     Type          
-------------------- -------- ------------- 
CODS                 NOT NULL NUMBER(5)     
NUME                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
PREN                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
```

CODS is a PRIMARY KEY.

I am trying to do this

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD CONSTRAINT student_cods_df DEFAULT stud_seq.nextval FOR cods;
```

and I get an error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

I'm using SQL Developer if anyone wants to know.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? This is only possible with Oracle 12 or newer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax has some issues; you probably need:

```
ALTER TABLE student modify cods DEFAULT stud_seq.nextval
```

Notice that you can use this from Oracle 12c on; if you need a solution for a different version, you'll find many answers in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Oracle+auto+increment); among the others, you may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037303/autoincrement-in-oracle-to-already-created-table)